# Devise:encrypted_password manually and add to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In a rails project, I want manage my users by admin, it means that admin can `add new user`, `update username and password` and `delete a user`. Now I write below code to do this actions. By below code, I can `update` and `delete` a user, but when I want `add new user to database`, the default validation of devise is work fine,(like `password can't blank), but when I click on`submit` to add user, page is redirect to previous page, but user don't add to database.

For manage user, I use `devise` and I create a `userscontroller`. I have below code:
`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end

end
```

`app/views/users/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`rootes.rb`

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

I think for add user to database, I have to `encrypted my password` and then add `email` and `encrypted_password` to database. But I don't know how can I do this. Any idea?

`server log`:

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-12 15:49:20 +0430
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-12 15:49:43 +0430
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"FNiCblkf5kmRxAWtoRcTvwu8LZ/Rm
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-12 15:49:43 +0430
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-12 15:49:43 +0430
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER
  Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 17.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you post errors in log?

Comment: I edit the question and add server log.

Comment: Can you comment Registerable module to override default registration behavior as you want to add user from Admin and check again.

Comment: I don't ovveride the default Registerable. I remove `:registerable` from model, but I get error and add this again to model.